# Setting reference to UIButton globally

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

So I have a UIButton that is added to the window so it can be visible over any presented controllers, and it has various states I animate between.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.addSubview(customButton)
```

This works fine but, I want to show/hide it for particular views within the app, and I'm struggling with the best way to go about this. Would adding it as a global reference be very frowned upon?

```
let customButton: CustomButton = CustomButton()

class NavigationClass: UINavigationController {
.....
}
```

This seems the easiest way as then I can access it from any class...

```
class ControllerClass: UIViewController {
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        customButton.isHidden = true
        customButton.resetState()
    }
}
```

Is there any reason I shouldn't do this, or a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create ParentViewController with Static button if you need and implement behavior for all Child Controllers.